# How to pass Firebase Custom Token to client?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a project that requires the usage of login via Facebook and Google, so I picked Firebase to speed up the process of authentication; However, the user must also be able to login via LINE(a messaging app popular in SEA).

Currently, I have implemented:

Line Login-> Finish Login -> Redirect to Cloud Functions -> Verify Line's Access_Token -> Create a User In Firebase from LINE's ID Token -> Create Custom Token from Firebase User

All that's left is to implement signInWithCustomToken and then get the idToken from firebase to send to my api for authorisation.

Now, the signIn process should be handled by the client side, but I am not sure how to pass the customToken to the client side(Our backend api and frontend client is separated).

I could pass it in a query param as I redirect the user to the frontend, but I am not sure if that's the best way to go about it.

What should I do?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "pass the customToken to the client side".  WIth Firebase, you run signInWithCustomToken on the client, and the client gets the token directly for use with future backend calls.  There is no "passing to the client" in this case.

Comment: Right now, my LINE login redirects to the cloud function(my callback), which after verifying all the info from LINE creates a firebase user and the custom token. Basically, I want to redirect the user from the cloud function to the actual web app(SPA with React), where the signInWithCustomToken can be ran. That said, I don't know what I should do to let the web app know the customToken and use that to sign in. Sorry, I'm new to firebase and OAuth in general. :/

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "Line Login-> Finish Login -> **Redirect to Cloud Functions**" Do you call an HTTPS Cloud Function from your front-end?

Comment: Line Login gives you a link to a LINE login screen that you can use for your users to login. After the user has logged in to LINE, it redirects to any link you set for it to redirect to with the url params being the authorisation code and state, so ?code=xxxxxx&state=xxxxx. You're supposed to use said code to issue a token from line and verify that the login is correct. I decided to use cloud function to be the redirect url for the LINE Login and verify the token there as well as create a user in firebase. So up until this point, nothing is called from my front-end. It's just LINE to Functions

Comment: This worked fine. I tried using the LINE login link and it did what I expected. It created the user in firebase with the LINE uuid as the uid. I was also able to create a custom token from it in functions. Now, I just need to pass it back to the front-end client to sign in.

Comment: Essentially, the user login flow from my frontend should be like this: "Login Via Line Button" -> LINE Login Page(Provided by Line) -> Redirect to cloud functions -> Redirect back to my front-end page with the customToken and signed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After the user has logged in to LINE, it redirects to any link you set
> for it to redirect to with the url params being the authorisation code
> and state, so ?code=xxxxxx&state=xxxxx ...  I decided to use cloud function to be the redirect url for the LINE Login

If I understand correctly, instead of directly redirecting LINE to the Cloud Function, you should probably redirect to a page of your web application which, in turns, calls a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) ([passing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) the `code` and `state`values as arguments).

This Cloud Function verifies the token as well as creates a user in Firebase and when this is done, sends back the token to the page of your web application. You then have all the elements to call the `signInWithCustomToken()` method.